# plotting hypervolumes from hypervolume() in 3d

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I am using the [hypervolume](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hypervolume/index.html) package to construct hypervolumes in n-dimensional space.

I can't figure out how to tweak 3d plots when plot() is operated over an object of class 'Hypervolume' or 'HypervolumeList'. The arguments are listed in the [package documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hypervolume/hypervolume.pdf) for function 'plot.HypervolumeList' (pg 21).

Example using data included with package:

```
# Call data and run routine that will create a HypervolumeList
require(hypervolume)
data(finch)
doHypervolumeFinchDemo = T
demo(finch)

# Create 3d plot of HypervolumeList
plot(hv_finches_list, pairplot = F)
```

Specific questions follow. Included code that I tried--but doesn't work.

1. How do I change the size of the data points?

   ```
   plot(hv_finches_list, pairplot = F, cex.data = 5)
   ```
2. How do I choose whether to plot the uniformly random points?

   ```
   plot(hv_fiches_list, pairplot = F, showrandom = T)
   ```
3. Is it possible to add centroids or contours to the 3d plot?

   ```
   plot(hv_finches_list, pairplot = F, showcentroid = T)
   ```

Comment: The `plot.HypervolumeList` function incorrectly passes the `cex.data` argument to a `cex` parameter in its call to `points3d`, but since it is using rgl-plotting it should have used the `size` parameter. You should be able to fix it.

Comment: @BondedDust Is it supposed to be a simple case of changing the argument name? `plot(hv_finches_list, pairplot = F, size = 10)` doesn't increase the size of datapoints.

Comment: You didn't read my comment correctly. The problem is in the code, not in your use of it. You need to edit the code (or contact the package maintainer to have them fix it) if you want it to work as advertised.