# R: Volumes around points in 3d scatterplot

Tags: r, plot, 3d, scatter-plot

I would like to generate a 3d scatterplot that includes volumes around groups of points. Something like [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/jmp-11-essential/9781612906850/EG_05_3d_Scatterplot.xhtml), but in R.

These could be rough spheroids or something more complex like in the image linked above, honestly I'm just trying to illustrate hypervolume overlap for a presentation. It seems like I could build a kernel density estimation for each set of points and plot that, but I can't figure out how to do so.

The scatterplot that I am using as a base is very similar to that generated by this code:

```
# Code from http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/impressive-package-for-3d-and-4d-graph-r-software-and-data-visualization#change-the-color-by-groups
library(plot3D)

# Set up data
data(iris)
x <- sep.l <- iris$Sepal.Length
y <- pet.l <- iris$Petal.Length
z <- sep.w <- iris$Sepal.Width

# Make 3d scatterplot with colors by category
scatter3D(x, y, z, bty = "g", pch = 18, 
  col.var = as.integer(iris$Species), 
  col = c("#1B9E77", "#D95F02", "#7570B3"),
  pch = 18, ticktype = "detailed",
  colkey = list(at = c(2, 3, 4), side = 1, 
  addlines = TRUE, length = 0.5, width = 0.5,
  labels = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")) )
```

Bonus: If you can tell me how to edit the *hypervolume()* package so that plotting a hypervolume object works properly you would have my undying gratitude. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550758/plotting-hypervolumes-from-hypervolume-in-3d) for better description of the problems.

Comment: Have a look at [Computing and Displaying Isosurfaces in R - Feng & Tierney 2008](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v028i01).

Comment: Thanks! But is there an equivalent method in the plot3D universe? I'd rather not have to switch my plot over to an rgl implementation.

Comment: A few things: `contour3d` has an argument called `engine` that allows you to change from default of rgl.  Also, a quick look reveals that there is an `isosurf3D` function in `plot3D`, and the note on it says it's based on a function from Feng & Tierney's package `misc3d`.  You might also want to check out the [vignettes for plot3D](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/index.html).